# File character matching and adding a character shell script

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I have a file with format as below

```
ABD|66732|987|01/06/2019 10:00|I
ABD|66732|927|01/06/2019 10:01|I
ABD|66732|W917|01/06/2019 10:02|I
ABD|66732|947|01/06/2019 10:03|I
ABD|66732|W977|01/06/2019 10:04|I
ABD|66732|997|01/06/2019 10:05|I
```

I want to  prefix 'W' after second '|' on each line if W is not present already. I need to do this using bash script.
I tried using sed and I am able replace but how to conditionally replace using sed?

Comment: `I tried using sed and I am able replace` please click [edit] to add that code to the question

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the following pattern:

```
^(([^|]+\|){2})([^W])
```

And replace with:

```
\1W\3
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CdTd61/2).

Comment: please do not use sites like regex101 for cli tools, sed doesn't support features likes non-capturing group

Comment: @Sundeep Thanks, I didn't know that. Would the updated pattern work in sed now? Or should I delete the answer altogether?

Comment: there's [BRE/ERE differences](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y), so you need `sed -E 's/^(([^|]+\|){2})([^W])/\1W\3/'`

Comment: No, it won't. sed uses posix basic regular expressions.

Comment: thanks @Sundeep sed -E 's/^(([^|]+\|){2})([^W])/\1W\3/' works.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` is better suited for field based proccessing:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {sub(/^[^W]/, "W&", $3)} 1' ip.txt
ABD|66732|W987|01/06/2019 10:00|I
ABD|66732|W927|01/06/2019 10:01|I
ABD|66732|W917|01/06/2019 10:02|I
ABD|66732|W947|01/06/2019 10:03|I
ABD|66732|W977|01/06/2019 10:04|I
ABD|66732|W997|01/06/2019 10:05|I
```

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}` set `|` as input and output field separator
- `sub(/^[^W]/, "W&", $3)` search and replace the first match for only the third field

  - `^[^W]` will work only if first character of third field isn't `W`
  - `W&` to add `W` as a prefix to the matched character